# Pages can't open file: error -60005

Tags: macos, permission, pages, iwork

I have a .pages file I've worked on as recently as May. When I tried to open it the Console.app reported:

`9/2/16 7:21:44.392 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[337]: Error -60005 creating authorization`

The file didn't open. I created a new document and save it, and was able to reopen it; though Pages DID throw the same error (but the file window opened).

I deleted and re-downloaded Pages from the App store. Preview.app confirms the app has readable content.

I have done first aid on the disk, and am on El Cap 10.11.6.

Pages is up to date, 5.6.2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I called Mac support and they had me delete some files from my computers' cache and then reboot in safe mode and open the document. I then deleted my trash can and rebooted in regular mode and the problem was fixed.